# Error Looping Through Deserialise Json List (.Net 2 )Vb

Tags: json, vb.net

How do I iterate through a deserialize jason and assign the name/value to a textbox

```
Dim ProductDetail = serializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of ChinaVJsonDeserializer.RootObject()))(ReturnStr)
        Dim Product As ChinaVJsonDeserializer.RootObject
        For Each Product In ProductDetail
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder
            sb = sb.AppendLine("id:" & ProductDetail.product_id)
            sb = sb.AppendLine("Model_Code:" & ProductDetail.model_code)


            Me.txtProductDetail.Text = sb.ToString
```

It returns this error
    System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.MissingMemberException: Public member 'Product' on type 'List(Of RootObject())' not found.

sample json

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "product_id": 222,
        "model_code": "xxx",
        "full_product_name": "xxx",
        "short_product_name": "xxx",
        "product_url": "xxx",
        "category_name": "xxx",
        "subcategory_name": "xxx",
        "subcategory_url": "xxx",
        "date_product_was_launched": "xxx",
        "main_picture": "xxx",
        "currency": "xxx",
        "price": "xx.xx",
        "retail_price": "xx.xx",
        "ean": "xxx",
        "continuity": "xxx",
        "overview": "xxx",
        "specification": "xxx",
        "additional_images": [
            "xxx",
            "xxx",
            "xxx",
            "xxx",
            "xxx",
            "xxx",
            "xxx",
            "xxx",
            "xxx"
        ],
        "related_products": [
            {
                "product_id": 22
            },
            {
                "product_id": 22
            },
            {
                "product_id": 22
            },
            {
                "product_id": 22
            },
            {
                "product_id": 22
            },
            {
                "product_id": 22
            }
        ],
        "package": {
            "weight_kg": 2.22,
            "height_mm": 3,
            "width_mm": 33,
            "depth_mm": 2
        },
        "status": "xxx",
        "meta_keyword": "xxx",
        "meta_description": "xxx"
    }
]
}
```

Class

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.text
Imports System.Net


Public Class ChinaVJsonDeserializer

Public Class RelatedProduct
    Public Property product_id() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_product_id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_product_id = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_product_id As Integer
End Class

Public Class Package
    Public Property weight_kg() As Double
        Get
            Return m_weight_kg
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            m_weight_kg = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_weight_kg As Double
    Public Property height_mm() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_height_mm
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_height_mm = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_height_mm As Integer
    Public Property width_mm() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_width_mm
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_width_mm = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_width_mm As Integer
    Public Property depth_mm() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_depth_mm
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_depth_mm = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_depth_mm As Integer
End Class

Public Class Product
    Public Property product_id() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_product_id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_product_id = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_product_id As Integer
    Public Property model_code() As String
        Get
            Return m_model_code
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_model_code = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_model_code As String
    Public Property full_product_name() As String
        Get
            Return m_full_product_name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_full_product_name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_full_product_name As String
    Public Property short_product_name() As String
        Get
            Return m_short_product_name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_short_product_name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_short_product_name As String
    Public Property product_url() As String
        Get
            Return m_product_url
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_product_url = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_product_url As String
    Public Property category_name() As String
        Get
            Return m_category_name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_category_name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_category_name As String
    Public Property category_url() As String
        Get
            Return m_category_url
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_category_url = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_category_url As String
    Public Property subcategory_name() As String
        Get
            Return m_subcategory_name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_subcategory_name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_subcategory_name As String
    Public Property subcategory_url() As String
        Get
            Return m_subcategory_url
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_subcategory_url = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_subcategory_url As String
    Public Property date_product_was_launched() As String
        Get
            Return m_date_product_was_launched
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_date_product_was_launched = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_date_product_was_launched As String
    Public Property main_picture() As String
        Get
            Return m_main_picture
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_main_picture = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_main_picture As String
    Public Property currency() As String
        Get
            Return m_currency
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_currency = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_currency As String
    Public Property price() As String
        Get
            Return m_price
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_price = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_price As String
    Public Property retail_price() As String
        Get
            Return m_retail_price
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_retail_price = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_retail_price As String
    Public Property ean() As Long
        Get
            Return m_ean
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Long)
            m_ean = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ean As Long
    Public Property continuity() As String
        Get
            Return m_continuity
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_continuity = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_continuity As String
    Public Property overview() As String
        Get
            Return m_overview
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_overview = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_overview As String
    Public Property specification() As String
        Get
            Return m_specification
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_specification = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_specification As String
    Public Property additional_images() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return m_additional_images
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of String))
            m_additional_images = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_additional_images As List(Of String)
    Public Property related_products() As List(Of RelatedProduct)
        Get
            Return m_related_products
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of RelatedProduct))
            m_related_products = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_related_products As List(Of RelatedProduct)
    Public Property package() As Package
        Get
            Return m_package
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Package)
            m_package = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_package As Package
    Public Property status() As String
        Get
            Return m_status
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_status = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_status As String
    Public Property meta_keyword() As String
        Get
            Return m_meta_keyword
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_meta_keyword = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_meta_keyword As String
    Public Property meta_description() As String
        Get
            Return m_meta_description
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_meta_description = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_meta_description As String
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property products() As List(Of Product)
        Get
            Return m_products
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Product))
            m_products = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_products As List(Of Product)
End Class

End Class
```

Comment: We'd need to see a sample of the "jason" data and the classes used.  the use of `ProductDetail` with sb seems wrong though - that looks like it is possibly a collection

Comment: You might find [this tool helpful](http://jsontodatacontract.azurewebsites.net/) - it will build a vb.net class based upon a JSON input.

Comment: The Class is not the probs, I got the above class from another tool.

Comment: No one to help? @Plutonix

Comment: what does the "(.NET 2)" signify in the title?  Also, what tool generated the classes (because they are wrong/do not match that json)?

Comment: Json2Csharp (www.json2csharp.com)  generated the classes in CSharp, I then converted to vb.net (www.deconverter.sharpdevelop.net/). I am coding with Visual Studio 2005, so .net 2 was ment to mean .net framework 2.0.  Please point me in the right direction .Many thanks for your time. @Plutonix

Comment: What serializer are you using? The std `JavaScriptSerializer` is for NET 3.5 and the same for Newton (I think).  One tool I used made a mess of the json classes, yours are not bad.  You dont need the `ChinaVJsonDeserializer` class, and as shown, `Product.ean` is string.  The RootObject contains a list/array of Products but itself is not an array/list, so: `jss.Deserialize(Of Rootobject)(jstr)` will work with the NET serializer and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(jstr)` for Newton.  I'd post an answer, but again I dont know what you are using.

Comment: Am using: System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer. Again thanks, let me work on your observation, hope it works @Plutonix

Comment: As you can see on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) the JavaScriptSerializer is listed as a NET 3.5 addition.  If I change the FrameWork to 2.0, neither `JavaScriptSerializer` nor Newton's will load or work - so I dont know how you are even able to reference the assemblies.  You might want to check that you are really using VS2005/Net 2.0.

Comment: Lemme have a second look

Comment: I had a second look and it still points to VS2005/Net 2.0 and after effecting/correcting your observations its now popping this error: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'RootObject' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. @Plutonix

Comment: Enumerable was added in NET 3.5 as well.  Why not DL VS2013 Community?

Comment: I think its time to upgrade. a million thanks for your time. @plutonix